# How to localize ADTs Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

We are using ADTs for our Liferay 7 project. The ADTs have to support at least two languages. We created our own portlet and I discovered that you can use `<@liferay_ui["message"] key="…" />`. However, that utilizes the global language file in Liferay.

My question is, how do I achieve looking into my portlet's language file? Do I have to use JSPs for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most advisable thing is to create for example, a "**core-hook**" where you have all the available languages with their respective files and their translations. It is more organized than having languages at the portlet level.

I've given you an example with gradle that in the end is the same using the technology you use

Example: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/gradle/overrides/resource-bundle-override

```
${languageUtil.get(locale, "add-blog-entry", "Add Blog")}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I have created a hook to re-write core JSPs, for example, but I am not sure what you're suggesting I rewrite.

Comment: I have edited my comment. I've given you an example for Liferay 6.2, you just have to use the Liferay 7 markup.  @pydoge

Comment: but that is not working. It does exactly what I wrote in the first post - looks into the global language bundle. I want to get the translation from for example [here](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/7.0.x/modules/apps/web-experience/asset/asset-publisher-web/src/main/resources/content). So in my asset publisher ADT, I want to access this language bundle. `${languageUtil.get(locale, "add-blog-entry", "Add Blog")}` <-- this does not access portlet language bundle, but portal language bundle. You also sent a link to override portal-wide language bundle.

Comment: ADT work in the portal context no in the portet context. What you want is not posible. The proposed solution is the way to go. You need to put the translation into the portal space.

Comment: Marking as resolved. This is stupid (on Liferay's part) but correct.

Comment: Welcome to the liferay world =) @pydoge